# RapidAPI integration with react app using Vite problem with Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, netlify, rapidapi

I am using vite, react, netlify and rapidapi for my project. All requests and functionalities were working perfectly when i was working on localhost and vscode. But when I deployed to the netlify, I ran into error which states e.slice is not a function. While debugging, i found out that in network tab in developer tools, the response from the rapidapi was code 403, and the message that you are not subscribed to the api.

```
export const exerciseOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': import.meta.env.VITE_RAPID_API_KEY,
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };

export const youtubeOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': import.meta.env.VITE_RAPID_API_KEY,
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'youtube-search-and-download.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

export const fetchData = async (url, options) => {  
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

I am running this code, works fine on localhost but not working on netlify as i described above.

Comment: Most likely, your `VITE_RAPID_API_KEY` is not defined on Netlify. Set the environment variable on Netlify and it should work.

Comment: @technophyle I've defined the api key properly on netlify...... If I haven't.... How can the network tab in developer tools will display that key in headers seaction

Comment: Ok, maybe share the screenshot of the Network tab request.